# What happens when I execute a unix shell script using a '.' command?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

For example, when I say `. .bashrc` on my Linux command prompt, is there a corresponding binary/script that gets executed in place of the first dot? If the dot itself is a command, where is its location?

Comment: I do not think the 'belongs-on-serverfault' tag is appropriate here. Shell scripting is a valid programming topic.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/36052/what-is-the-purpose-of-source-as-a-shell-command) on Server Fault.

Comment: Been asked and answered a couple of time already. Good luck finding the dups, though...

Comment: Found one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922651/unix-command-line-execute-with-dot-vs-without

Comment: Surprised why it didn't show up when I searched for it :-). Something for Jeff & team to chew on?
Am not sure if I should edit the earlier question, or leave this one as is, so there's a greater chance of someone finding the question.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip/176788#176788

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `.` operator is shorthand for the `source` Bash builtin (as pointed out by John Kugelman below). Typing

```
help .
```

or

```
help source
```

at the Bash prompt will give you some information. For more on how `source` works, see http://www.ss64.com/bash/period.html.

Comment: +1 Key is that it is a shell builtin, not a separate binary. You can type `help` at a bash prompt to see all of the other builtins.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally I want to point out that you don't "execute" anything with it (in terms of fork/exec), which is very important (and probably the only reason '.' exists).

Comment: One key point - a consequence of the dot command not executing anything - is that if the dotted script sets variables, it sets them in the shell that dots the script, not in some sub-shell.