# What is the meaning of ". filename" (period space filename) in Bash?

Tags: bash, period

What does a command with format [period][space][filename] mean?

Example:

```
. ./setup.sh
```

Also in the `.bashrc` file, we have a line like that:

```
. "$HOME/.bashrc"
```

What does this mean?

Comment: From the bash manual, http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_002e

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens when I execute a unix shell script using a '.' command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107808/what-happens-when-i-execute-a-unix-shell-script-using-a-command)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `.` operator is also known as `source`.

According to [this forum thread](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/177636-dot-operator-space-parameter-not-set.html), the first `.` is the command `source` to read and execute commands from the filename given as argument.
The second `.` is the current directory.

```
. ./setup.sh
```

is the same as

```
source ./setup.sh
```

or

```
source setup.sh
```

if the `./`, the current directory, is in the `PATH` environment variable.

Here is the manual for that: http://ss64.com/bash/source.html

This is typically used to run the script in the current shell to help set up the environment for execution, as well as to set up aliases.

Comment: Worth mentioning: `source` is a Bashism, `.` is understood by any POSIX conformant shell.