# A usage of dot in bash script

Tags: bash

What does dot mean in line 8 of the following code snippet, from the source of `/etc/profile` in Mac OS X Mavericks terminal.

```
  1 # System-wide .profile for sh(1)
  2 
  3 if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
  4         eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
  5 fi
  6 
  7 if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
  8         [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
  9 fi
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/232932/in-a-bash-script-what-does-a-dot-followed-by-a-space-and-then-a-path-mean

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dot space ( \[dot\]\[space\]\[filename\] )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014478/dot-space-dotspacefilename)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash, `.` is another way to spell `source`. So this line is the same as this:

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && source /etc/bashrc
fi
```

`source` interprets the file as if the content was included at the location of the `source` command. The difference with executing it is that it can set `alias` or define `function` or variables.

Comment: Technically, `source` is another way to spell `.`. `.` is a standard POSIX command; `source` is a more readable synonym provided by some shells.

Comment: However, note that `source` should not be used in `.profile`, which may be read by other POSIX-compatible shells which don't understand the `source` command.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html):

> When a file is sourced (by typing either source filename or . filename
>   at the command line), the lines of code in the file are executed as if
>   they were printed at the command line. This is particularly useful
>   with complex prompts, to allow them to be stored in files and called
>   up by sourcing the file they are in.

Comment: Thank you for this good explanation on the verb "sourced", as seen also in this [doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).