# What does it mean when shell command starts with a dot?

Tags: linux, shell

I have snippet from a shell script. 
Wondering what does the line starting with a 'dot' mean?
It doesn't work when I try on Mac

```
test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

set -e

. /lib/lsb/init-functions
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unix command line execute with . (dot) vs. without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922651/unix-command-line-execute-with-dot-vs-without)

Comment: The dot command should definitely work on a Mac, too; but you probably don't have a file named `/lib/lsb/init-functions`, which is a feature of the Linux Standard Base (Linux is a different operating system than MacOS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` is a shorthand for the [`source`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(command)) command in bash and similar shells. It will execute the contents of the script passed to it as a parameter (`/lib/lsb/init-functions` in this case) in the current context.