# Exit code from child script to parent script

Tags: bash, shell

I have the below parent script which calls a child script.

parent.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
export home=`pwd`
echo "calling child"
. ${home}/bin/child.sh
retn_code=$?
if (retn_code -ne 0)
then
    exit $retn_code
else
    echo "successful"
fi
exit 0
```

child.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 1
```

When I execute the parent script, the exit status of 1 is not getting captured in parent script. The last line of the log printed is "calling child" and there are no lines printed after that in log.

Is there something I am missing while getting the exit status from child to parent?

Comment: It's not a child. You are `.` it. It's the same process.

Comment: `(retn_code -ne 0)` is now how you compare numbers in bash.

Comment: Ok.. apologies.i am new to scripting. In this case, how to pass the exit status from the subscript to main script?

Comment: If the script is meant to be sourced - `return`. If the script is meant to be run as separate child, then don't source it.

Comment: `if ./bin/child.sh; then echo "successful"; else exit; fi` -- and notice it's not using the `.` command anymore.

Comment: The marked duplicate is not really a duplicate.  The issue here is not numerical comparison but an incorrect use of `.`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, granted, but I'm calling that a typo. Can add an additional duplicate for it if you feel strongly, though.

Comment: BTW, consider `home=$PWD` instead of `home=$(pwd)`; the former is considerably faster to run.

Comment: `rc=$?; [[ $rc = 0 ]] || exit $rc` This answered my own question, may answer this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90418/exit-shell-script-based-on-process-exit-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` does not call the child, it runs its code.  So if the child script calls `exit`, the parent exits.  You want to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
home=$(pwd)
echo "calling child"
if "${home}"/bin/child.sh; then
    echo success
else
    exit   # status returned by child will propagate
fi
exit 0
```

Note that it's very odd to use the variable `home` here.  If you want it defined in child.sh, IMO it would be clearer to write `if home=$(pwd) ./bin/child.sh; then ...`. Your usage of `export` implies that you want it defined in child.sh, but I suspect you don't actually want that.  It's not pertinent to the question, so I've just removed what I believe is an unnecessary export.

Comment: This could/should have been marked duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922651/unix-command-line-execute-with-dot-vs-without -- I was about to edit the duplicate list to add that when you reopened.

Comment: BTW, your `if` is backwards; it's currently `exit`ing in the success case, and echoing `successful` in the failure case.

Comment: ...whereas in the new version because the `!` is inverting `$?`, the `exit` no longer propagates the intended value.

Comment: @Biffen, `exit` uses `$?` by default, really. The trick (which early versions of this answer haven't gotten right) is to write the code so the child's exit status is still _in_ `$?` when the `exit` is reached.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Reversed the logic to match the OP.  Agree that this should be marked duplicate, but not sure of what.